# How do I sync couchdb views?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I am starting to use nodejs and couchdb, and I wanted to keep my view functions synchronized to the server because I want to keep them in version control.

I thought of rolling my own solution, involving storing the views along with a hash of their own code, but someone else must have created something like this already.

Comment: I wrote couchdb-update-views which is a command line tool to help keep views up to date. https://github.com/nisaacson/couchdb-update-views

Comment: @Noah I am going to give it a run, but I think this comment is the correct answer.

Comment: @Noah I am using your package. It solves my problem very well.

Comment: I just pushed a new version to npm which compares the map and reduce function inside each view for changes. The old version just compared overall view names

Comment: @Noah I didn't realize that. But I'll upgrade. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use CouchDB replication with a replication filter designed to only select design documents.